# java insert at end linked list

Tags: hyperlink, insert, eclipselink, insertion

my code for insert at the end was not working 
help me please
 how can i insert element at the end of the linked list 
in java linked list is really confusing ,, anyone please answer my question please 
before i got some other doubts nd got it cleared thanks frnds fr doing so 
please answer me again how insert element to the end of the list in my code

```js
        import    java . util.Scanner;
    
    
    
    class node
    {
        int i,q; 
         node next;
         node prev;
    }
    
    class link{
        public static void main(String args[])
    {
         linkk l = new linkk();
         
      l.op();
         int user=0;   
         while(user!=10)
        {Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
          if(user==1)
          {
           System.out.println("\nenter data\n");
           
           l.create(a.nextInt());
         
          }System.out.println("\n1.create link\n2.insert beginning\n3.insert middle\n4.insert end\n5.delete data\n6.reverse");
    user=a.nextInt();
    }
    if(user==2)
    l.insertbeg();
    if(user==3)
     l.insertmid();
    if(user==4)
     l.insertend();
    if(user==5)
     l.del();
    if(user==6)
     l.reverse();
    if(user==7)
    l.display();
      
     }
    
    }
    
    class  linkk
    {  
    node temp4;
    int ch,add,cnt=0,t=0,b;
    node p= new node();
    node q;
     node last;
    node first=new node;
    
    public boolean isEmpty()
    
    {
    
        return first == null;
    
    }
    
    public  void insertbeg()
    {
    }
    
    public  void insertmid()
    {
    }
    public void insertend()
    {//this is my code but not working

     p=new node();
 System.out.println("enter data"); 
 p.i=b.nextInt();
  temp=first;
 while(temp.next!=null)
 temp=temp.next;
 temp.next=p;
 p.next=null;
cnt++;

    }
    public  void del()
    {
    } 
    public  void reverse()
    {
    }
    public  void display()
    {
    }
    public  void create(int val)
    {   
      first.i=val;
    
      first.next=null;
      cnt++;   
            }
     public void ob()
     {
     }
     public void op()
     {
    }
    }
```

Comment: public void insertend()
{  p=new node();
 System.out.println("enter data"); 
 p.i=b.nextInt();
 temp=first;
 while(temp.next!=null)
 temp=temp.next;
 temp.next=p;
 p.next=null;
cnt++;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterate until the last node and then add your new node with the last node's next pointer.

Try something like:

```
public void insertend(node newNode) {
    node nextNode = headNode;
    while (nextNode.next != null) {
        nextNode = nextNode.next;
    }
    nextNode.next = newNode;
}
```

Comment: sir is that headnode is same as first node whish i have used rgt

Comment: if   im using public void insertend(new newnode) then while calling what should i should use

Comment: this is how you can call.. `node n = new node(); node.i=10; node.q=20; insertend(n);`

Comment: but insert end is void na sir should i change tat

Comment: that's return type and we are not changing it.

Comment: sir im calling that iinsertend by l.insertend();

Comment: public static void insertend(node newnode)

Comment: when i did that the compiler shows error the calling statement

Comment: you need to pass newnode as argument which you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

It is just .add(object) as specified here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: can any body please type the correct code to insert at end for my pg

Comment: Why do you "search" the end of the list yourself? In http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#addLast%28E%29 there is addLast method which appends a new item to the end of the list. (It also has a addFirst method)

Comment: The add() method without an position argument also adds to the end of the list.